# CakePHP how to set a message from Model?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.2

I'm trying to send a specific message from Model in `beforeSave()` method. Flash messages don't work. I could send this message from Controller and use some parameters but I don't this this best solution. Use of `print` isn't good either.

So my question is how to send any message to controller/view from model?

Comment: Why would you want to send a message. Can you be more specific what you are doing? Maybe also post some code? Usually its the other way around. Controllers will work with models and invoke methods and return something to continue.

Comment: +1. If you need to 'communicate' a message from the Model to the Controller (i.e. something more than *'it failed'*), throwing an `Exception` may be an option. Read this chapter in the documentation [Exceptions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/exceptions.html)

Comment: Exception idea is good. Return message is supposed to be about data passed to model, so I will do it through validation this time. But I'm concerned how should I do it when I will need to return message that is caused by some processing in `afterSave()` callback or somewhere where validation is useless. `Exception` is good but it force to use of try/catch in controller or custom error handling. I was thinking rather about how to hook to **flash messages** from Model.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to bubble an error message, try this

in your model :

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()){
    if($not_ok){
        $this->error = __('My error message');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

in your controller :

```
public function add(){
    $save = $this->Modelname->save($this->request->data);
    if(!$save){
        $this->Session->setFlash($this->Modelname->error);
        $this->redirect($this->referer());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well Session->setFlash() will not work, obviously, as it's part of a Session component, but
Session component uses static singleton class CakeSession, which has method CakeSession::write() all you've to do is pass array to write method that would have same structure as Session::setFlash() would generate and therefore when you use Session::flash() in view you will get same result as from setFlash() from controller.

For refrence: http://api.cakephp.org/2.2/class-CakeSession.html

Snippet from comment, to be placed in Model method.

```
App::uses('CakeSession','Model/Datasource');            
            CakeSession::write('Message', array(
                'flash' => array(
                    'message' => 'your message here',
                    'element' => 'default',
                    'params' => null,
                ),
            ));
```

Comment: Good idea, but I don't know how to use it. Can't find structure of from `setFlash()`, therefore it useless for me. In CakePHP 2.x  there is no `Session` class. There are `SessionComponent` and `SessionHelper`. Maybe someone else will know how to use it. I will make return messages through validation.

Comment: This a snipett I've put in my model to check if it works also I've created a setFlash() structure there. It's on cake 2.x, check if it works for you.
`App::uses('CakeSession','Model/Datasource');            
            CakeSession::write('Message', array(
                'flash' => array(
                    'message' => 'your message here',
                    'element' => 'default',
                    'params' => null,
                ),
            ));`

Also still I'm not sure if your Model should be responsible for this part of logic.

Updated the answer.

Comment: IMO directly accessing the Session for this from the Model is *not* advisable. Consider, for example, a situation where the same Model is used inside a Shell (command line / cron job). In this situation, there will be no Session, thus no way to output that message. Exceptions or another mechanism is a better solution. Retrieve that message in the Controller (or Shell) and output it in the way it should; `Session->setFlash()` in a Controller or write it to the "log" or send an email in case it is a Shell task

Answer (score 1):

By doing the following you will be able to set flashes within your models at any point and not have to worry about declaring them again within your controller because they will get automatically set within your app controller before the page is rendered.

In AppController:

```
public function beforeRender() {
  parent::beforeRender();
  $this->generateFlashes();
}

public function generateFlashes() {
  $flashTypes = array('alert', 'error', 'info', 'success', 'warning');
  $model = $this->modelClass;

  foreach($flashTypes as $type) {
    if(!empty($this->$model->$type)) {
      $message = '<strong>' . ucfirst($type) . ':</strong> ' . $this->$model->$type;
      $this->Flash->error($message, array('escape' => false));
    }
  }
}
```

In Model:

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()){
  if($not_ok){
    $this->error = __('My error message');
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

In Controller:

```
public function add(){
  // $this->modelClass will use whatever the actual model class is for this
  // controller without having to type it out or replace the word modelClass
  $save = $this->{$this->modelClass}->save($this->request->data);
  if(!save){
    // no need to set flash because it will get created in AppController beforeRender()
    $this->redirect($this->referer());
  }
}
```